Two types of sheafs of ideals agree?
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}$$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
I am trying to how that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed embedding of schemes (i.e. $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $Y$, and $f^\sharp:\O_Y\rightarrow f_*\O_X)$ is surjective) then for every affine open $U=\Spec A\subset Y$, there exists an ideal $I\subset A$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\cong \Spec A/I$. I tried going a topological route here, but that failed for reasons which are now obvious.
I am now trying to leverage the fact that I already know how to put a subscheme structure on $f(X)\subset Y$ which is induced by the sheaf of ideals:
$$I^f(U)=\{s\in \O_Y(U):\forall f(x)\in f(X)\cap U, s_{f(x)}\in\mathfrak m_{f(x)}\}$$
I think that if I can show that this is equal to the sheaf of ideals given by $\ker f^\sharp$ then I will be able to show the desired isomorphism on open affines. However,
while I can show that $\ker f^\sharp \subset I^f$, I cannot show the other inclusion, and so I now suspect that this may be an incorrect statement.
So is this equality true? If not how can go about showing that $f^{-1}(U)\cong \Spec A/I$ as schemes? (I can already show they are homeomorphic as topological spaces rather easily)

Consider the identity map $f: \{(x)\} = \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/x^2 \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/x^2$. Since these are singletons we identify ideal sheaves with their global sections with no issues. This is then a closed embedding with ideal sheaf $(0)$. On the other hand, $I_f = (x) \neq (0)$.
More generally, the $I_f$ you defined will always be radical, so non-radical ideals give many such counterexamples.
One straightforward way to prove the isomorphism you're looking for is to first prove a more general fact that there is a bijective correspondence between isomorphism classes of closed subschemes $f: Y \to X$ and quasi-coherent ideal sheaves $I \subset \mathcal{O}_X$ given as follows. Send a closed subscheme $f: Y \to X$ to the kernel of $f^\#$. In the other direction, take the closed subscheme given by $(\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/I), \mathcal{O}_X/I)$.
Once we know that all closed subschemes are of this form, we can then restrict ourselves to the case that $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y = (\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/I), \mathcal{O}_X/I)$. Since $I$ is quasi-coherent we can write $I = \tilde{\mathfrak{a}}$ for an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$, and then it is clear that $Y$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A/\mathfrak{a}$.
